# weka - improve an already trained model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, weka, data-analysis

Let's say I train my Neural Net (MultiLayer Perceptron) model with a set of data.

Then, tomorrow, I acquire MORE data. I want to improve my model with this second set of data. How can I do that in WEKA (explorer ideally)?

Comment: The trained model is not extendable. You have to retrain the Neural Net every time you add new data. It's because the weights assigned to nodes have to be altered in order to predict the new cases. To alter the weights of nodes, retrain is compulsory

Comment: So I have to retrain with the WHOLE set of data? The original set PLUS the new set?